# Google app Indexing API title versus keywords

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

I'm implementing Google's app indexing API for my app, following this tutorial https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/introduction

I was wondering if there is a distinction between the title of the google autocomplete suggestion for the app, and the keywords that are used for indexing. It would be great if I could match multiple keywords while only displaying a short title in the autocomplete suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no distinction. The keywords that are used in the title field are the exact keywords that will be matched to display those results in the Suggest results.

You can verify this by testing your implementation:

https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/test#test-autocompletions